# Previous view controller with delegate relationship does not take expected action

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a todo list that allows the user to add todos to a table view. On a separate view controller (`CompletedViewController`) the user can see previously-completed todos.

There is an `itemBarButton` in the `CompletedViewController` that should allow the user to clear the list of completed items, as well as clear the array of completed todos (`completedThings`) on the initial `ViewController`.

Creating an instance of `CompletedViewController` and setting the completedTodos array in `ViewController.swift`:

```
@IBAction func viewCompletedTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Completed") as? CompletedViewController {

        vc.completedTodos = completedThings

        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

the protocol in `CompletedViewController.swift`:

```
protocol CompletedCleared {
  func didClearCompleted() 
}
```

the method called when clicking the 'clear' `itemBarButton` in `CompletedViewController.swift`

```
 @objc func clearCompleted() {
    completedTodos = []
    tableView.reloadData()

    let vc = ViewController()

    vc.didClearCompleted()

}
```

conforming to the protocol in `ViewController.swift`

```
func didClearCompleted() {
    completedThings.removeAll()
}
```

This does not clear the list on the previous view controller. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Word of advice for the future. Try to be a bit more concise in your questions and copy and paste relevant bits of the code into your question.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! Will certainly do this in the future!

Comment: Feel free to [add your own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298924/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question-with-an-answer-inspired-by-another-ans/298925#298925), if you'd like, but please keep solution material out of the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set the delegate of the `CompletedViewController`. In `viewCompletedTapped` add this line after instantiating the view controller:

```
vc.delegate = self
```

Also make sure you use this delegate method in `CompletedViewController`. `clearCompleted` should probably look like this:

```
@objc func clearCompleted() {
    completedTodos = []
    tableView.reloadData()

    delegate?.didClearCompleted() 
}
```

Comment: I have added `vc.delegate = self` to `viewCompletedTapped` and the array is still not clearing when I call the `didClearCompleted` method

Comment: Looks like you may need to reload your table view after clearing the array. Add `myTable.reloadData()` after `completedThings.removeAll()`.

Comment: Still no luck. I don't think the `didClearCompleted` method is actually clearing the array that's being passed to the vc I initialize with the `viewCompletedTapped` action...

Comment: Awesome! You've solved it!  I guess I'm not quite understanding why I'm defining `var delegate: CompletedCleared?` in `CompletedViewController' and then setting `vc.delegate = self` in `ViewController` and then having to use `delegate?.didClearCompleted()`... Any tips where I can get clarification of these concepts?

Comment: I'd go back and read up on delegates and protocols again. You are defining a protocol called `CompletedCleared`. Your main vc conforms to that protocol by implementing `didClearCompleted()`. You then set the main vc as the delegate of `CompletedViewController`. In this way you are allowing the two objects to communicate with each other.